# NASM - Creating new lablels from existing labels

Tags: label, nasm

Can I create a new label in NASM, which points to a new memory location offset by a few bytes from a memory location pointed by another label.

For eg.: If label1 points to memory location 0x40h, is there a way to define label2 pointing to 0x44h using label1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but I'll answer what I think you want. Say you already have label1 one set up as

```
label1: db "Hello World", 10
```

and you just want to print the "world" bit. You can do so as follows (demonstrating as Linux with Intel syntax 32-bit, but it works in other cases):

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, label1
add ecx, 6             
mov edx, 6            
int 80h
```

I hope that makes sense, so you put the reference to "label1" in ecx, then increase that reference by the amount you wanted to offset.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a constant, which can be used like a label:

```
label2 equ label1+4
```